# SQL order by 2 date fields

Tags: mysql, sql

i am running a select query in MySQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
ORDER BY IF(duedate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', datetime_added, duedate) ASC
```

its ordering ASC but it puts all rows that have `0000-00-00 00:00:00` at the top but these should be at the bottom

How can I order my query in the following order:

```
duedate ASC
datetime_added ASC
sequence DESC
```

Comment: Might NULL be a more appropriate value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
from table1 
ORDER BY IF(duedate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '9999-12-31', duedate),         
         datetime_added ASC,
         sequence DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by:

```
SELECT * from table1 
ORDER BY 
duedate ASC,
duedate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
datetime_added ASC,
sequence DESC
```